# Deploy to Windows Phone 8 device from VM (RDP/RemoteFX)

Tags: windows-phone-8, remoting, rdp

I would like to move my WP8 development to a virtual machine. I know that the emulator won't run on top of a VM, so I'm wondering if I can deploy & debug directly to the device (via regular old USB). RemoteFX allegedly performs "USB redirection" which I assume is supposed to magically connect the phone up to my RDP session, and thus enable deployment. I was able to establish a RemoteFX connection with my VM, however when I try to deploy to my phone Visual Studio (within the VM) claims it cannot find a phone. (yes, I verified my phone is connected to my local machine)

tl;dr Does anyone know how to deploy to a physical Windows Phone from within a VM?

Comment: What kind of phone are you using? For Windows Phone 7 you would need to have the Zune client installed, for Windows Phone 8 a direct connection should work...

Comment: Sorry, my question is regarding WP8. Could you expand on what you mean by "direct connection"? I'm accessing the VM over the network via RDP/RemoteFX.

Comment: By direct connection I mean that no intermediate software should be required. Do you see the phone show up in explorer? It should be there to allow file transfers as well. You can also give the Windows Phone powertools a go to see if they will connect: http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: The phone shows up in in Explorer on my local hardware but it does not appear within the remote machine I'm connected to.

Comment: WPTools also does not detect a phone on the remote machine.

Comment: I'm not an expert on VMs, but it is clear that the problem lies in the USB redirection. As far as I know once the USB is connected to the VM it shouldn't show up on the regular PC anymore. Are you sure there's not an option in the VM anymore to force connect a specific USB device to the VM?

Comment: James, have you found a solution to this? I found the following link (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/11/26/remotefx-features-for-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) which highlights that you might need Windows 8 ENTERPRISE edition to make this possible. I've put EE on a VM, but am not seeing RemoteFX capabilities w/ my Windows Phone yet. Have you had any luck?

Comment: @bc3tech No luck yet. Although I'm hopeful since Microsoft will be rolling out DaaS on Azure soon, and as such I anticipate better USB support for VMs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I hope for the same! Let me know if you are able to figure anything out in the meantime, though.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is the first link that appears in google search for this problem. I am going to present you the solution from what it is there is Nokia development articles. Please go through [link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator).

The only important thing is to enable Intel VT-x option.

[image: Virtualization]